# Why does IFCjs cause runtime error on some computers?

Tags: webassembly, ifc

We encountered an error on some computers after upgrading web-ifc, web-ifc-three, and three

[Diff of the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxWUF.png)

The error is the following in dev environment

[Dev environment console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCOVx.png)

and different on production environment

[Production environment console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I9GB.png)

Everything seems to come from an error with the wasm file from web-ifc.

It looks a lot like this issue:

https://github.com/IFCjs/web-ifc/issues/75

But we have automated the retrieval of the wasm file to put it in the right file path from node_modules, so it's always the wasm of the installed version of web-ifc.

```
"ifcjs:setup": "cp ./node_modules/web-ifc/web-ifc.wasm ./public/files/",
```

This is how we get IFCLoader:

```
import { IFCLoader } from 'web-ifc-three/IFCLoader';
```

And then get the writing ifc api from it

```
const ifcLoader = new IFCLoader();
const ifcApi = ifcLoader.ifcManager.ifcAPI;
```

We use web-ifc to write ifc files.

Not every computer have this error and we didn't manage to understand why.

We don't know if it's related but share this with you either way.

We tested with the latest version of web-ifc (0.0.36), but we get another error:

[0.0.36 web-ifc error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh5l4.png)

We downgraded web-ifc, web-ifc-three to the previous version and this problem was fixed. The thing is we had another problem with these old versions so we can't go that old.

We also tried on different operating systems, computers and the classical reboot. None of it works.

Any help is appreciated =) Thank you very much!